# Drawing on a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I am making a simple drawing program. What i am trying to do is that i want to draw a line on a jframe as the mouse is dragged on the jframe, pretty much like the paintbrush application. As the mouse is pressed, line starts drawing and as mouse is released, the line ends. Similarly if mouse is pressed on any other point in JFrame, another line starts drawing. This is not that hard to do when making the program in single class but I am making the program in different packages and classes. What i am trying to do is that i want to place the Mouselistener of the jframe in different class and in that same class i want to write the draw function that draws on that jframe. i have tried different things but nothing seems to work. This is what i have done so far... I am new to Java so explanation with examples would really help.

GUI package
class gui

```
package Gui;

import Logic.Draw;
import Logic.MenuHandler;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class gui{

    public JFrame jf = new JFrame("Paint Brush");
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    JMenuBar jmb = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu jm = new JMenu("Options");
    JMenuItem jmi = new JMenuItem("Change Colour");
    JMenuItem jmi2 = new JMenuItem("Exit");


    public void make_gui()
    {
        jf.setSize(500, 500);
        jf.setLocation(370, 150);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jf.add(jmb);
        jf.setJMenuBar(jmb);

        jm.add(jmi);
        jm.add(jmi2);
        jmb.add(jm);

        jmi.setActionCommand("1");
        jmi2.setActionCommand("2");

        MenuHandler obj_mh = new MenuHandler(this);
        jmi.addActionListener(obj_mh);
        jmi2.addActionListener(obj_mh);


        jp.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        jf.add(jp);

        Draw obj_d = new Draw(this);
        jf.addMouseListener(obj_d);

        jf.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void make_colourChooser()
    {
        JFrame jf2 = new JFrame("Choose Colour");
        JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();
        JButton jb1 = new JButton("Red");
        JButton jb2 = new JButton("Blue");
        JButton jb3 = new JButton("Green");
        JButton jb4 = new JButton("Yellow");
        JButton jb5 = new JButton("Grey");
        JButton jb6 = new JButton("Black");
        JButton jb7 = new JButton("Orange");
        JButton jb8 = new JButton("Cyan");
        JButton jb9 = new JButton("Pink");


        jb1.setSize(200,200);
        jb1.setBackground(Color.red);
        jp2.add(jb1);

        jb2.setSize(200,200);
        jb2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        jp2.add(jb2);

        jb3.setSize(200,200);
        jb3.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        jp2.add(jb3);

        jb4.setSize(200,200);
        jb4.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        jp2.add(jb4);

        jb5.setSize(200,200);
        jb5.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        jp2.add(jb5);

        jb6.setSize(200,200);
        jb6.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        jp2.add(jb6);

        jb7.setSize(200,200);
        jb7.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        jp2.add(jb7);

        jb8.setSize(200,200);
        jb8.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        jp2.add(jb8);

        jb9.setSize(200,200);
        jb9.setBackground(Color.PINK);
        jp2.add(jb9);

        jf2.setSize(300,300);
        jf2.setLocation(400,150);

        jp2.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

        jf2.add(jp2);
        jf2.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Logic Package
class Draw

```
package Logic;

import Gui.gui;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Draw implements MouseListener{

    gui obj_g2 = new gui();

     int startpointX, endpointX;
     int startpointY, endpointY;

    public Draw(gui a) {

       obj_g2 = a;        
    }

    public Draw() {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        startpointX = e.getX();
        startpointY = e.getY();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {


    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

        endpointX = e.getX();
        endpointY = e.getY();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    public void draw(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawLine(startpointX, startpointY, endpointX, endpointY);
    }
}
```

Main class

```
package paintbrush;

import Gui.gui;

public class PaintBrush {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        gui obj = new gui();
        obj.make_gui();
    }

}
```

Comment: So all the classes compile correctly? you are just looking for organization?

Comment: You should have a component, which you've override the `paintComponent` of to implement your custom painting and onto which the `MouseListener` would then be registered to it. You should aim to make the component as self contained as possible and possible use a model of some kind to maintain the drawing information you need, making it easier to manage

Comment: yes program runs correctly, what i want to do now is use the draw method or any other method in class Draw and use it to draw lines on JFrame as the mouse is dragged on the jframe. i have tried numerous things but i can't figure out how to do it

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, you don't want to paint directly to the `JFrame`, maybe you should start with [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: Actually i am having a bit difficulty understanding those documents as i am new to java so right now i am really confused. If you could tell me what changes do i have to do in my program to be able to do what i want, that would really be easy to understand and helpful.

Comment: I answered a similar question 3 weeks ago.  Check out this [drawing application](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36552505/300257) and use it as a model for what you want.  Oh, for anyone else reading, you **never, never, never, never** draw directly on a JFrame.  You draw on a JPanel that is added to a JFrame.

Comment: problem is that as you can see in the code provided above, i have added jpanel on jframe in gui class in make_gui function and a draw function that draws on that jpanel which is added in jframe in gui class is written in another class named Draw. I am having difficulty understanding how to draw on that jpanel when my draw function is in another class